# Rig mesh Faces Missing

Tags: rendering, faces, error

[image]

I'm still kind of a novice at blender. This was a model that I made maybe a year ago and just reopened it and it looked like this. It should not have textures, just normal plane faces. Any ideas?

I've already tried to unhide faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in case I had hidden them, but nothing changed.

This was made with 2.82.7 and pretty sure the model was originally made with that or just a few versions before.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots Add the file

Comment: It might be just something wrong with my version of blender getting in a weird state because I just opened a new session and the default cube is also doing that.

Comment: it works fine for me, it may be a problem with your AMD driver? Try a previous one, or go into Render panel > Performance and enable High Quality Normals

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled Blender and it fix it.